# Is there a statement in flutter similar to the when case statement in kotlin?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is an example from kotlin:

```
binding.orderStatusTextView.text = when (status) {
    2 -> "bad"
    3 -> "not bad"
    4 -> "good"
    5 -> "excellent"
    else -> "New"
}
```

Comment: you might be looking for `switch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Yeasin Sheikh suggested you can use switch case like this.

```dart
String getStatus(int code){
    switch(code){
        case 2: return 'bad';
        case 3: return 'Not bad';
        case 4: return 'good';
        case 5: return 'Excellent';
        default: return "";
    }
}

_textController.text = getStatus(status);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Dart 3, the `switch` statement is equivalent to Kotlin's `when` statement:

```
void main() {
  int status = 4;

  final value = switch (status) {
    2 => 'bad',
    3 => 'not bad',
    4 => 'good',
    5 => 'excellent',
    _ => 'New'
  };

  print(value);
}
```

In Dart 2.0, using `switch` inside an anonymous function matches closely with Kotlin's `when` clause:

```
    final statusValue = 4;

    final value = (status) {
      switch (status) {
        case 2:
          return 'bad';
        case 3:
          return 'Not bad';
        case 4:
          return 'good';
        case 5:
          return 'Excellent';
        default:
          return "";
      }
    }(statusValue);

    print(value);
```